# Query active vCPU usage from AWS service limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

**Question:**

Is there a way to query my vCPU usage according to an AWS service limit API?

For example, I want to know how many G type instances AWS **thinks** I have running at that moment.

**Background:**

I am encountering an edge case for account limits when stopping/starting instances. Say, for example, my account limit for G type instances is 10. I run 10 instances of that type. Then I stop all 10. Once they are stopped, I immediately call start instance on all of them. I am seeing a "VcpuLimitExceeded" error from the API. But if I wait 10-30 seconds, the call succeeds!

I suspect this is because although the instances are stopped, the AWS quota api has not updated. So it thinks I still have 10 running, want to start another 10, and thus 20 is over my account limit of 10.

In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-EC2.html) it says that EC2 can take **minutes** to update service quotas. I want to confirm this suspicion by querying the AWS service/quota limit API for my current usage at the time when I see the error. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the "Service Quotas" service and click the "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)" block. You can then search for the limit you are looking for.

For "Running On-Demand G instances" you are taken to this page: https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1#!/services/ec2/quotas/L-DB2E81BA

Which shows your current usage:

[image]

Comment: huh. My services are in the ap-east-1 region which only exposes 20 quotas, while the screenshot you shared is in us-east-1 with 94 quotas. Perhaps this is a regional limitation.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. They likely have different numbers of machines in different regions. By the way, your comment that the calls work a while after stopping really helped me. I hit my limit and thought it was still counting stopped machines. But using this screen and waiting I saw the quota come back down.